# Merging multiple CSV's with different columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, powerbi

Lets say I have a CSV which is generated yearly by my business. Each year my business decides there is a new type of data we want to collect. So Year2002.csv looks like this:

```
Age,Gender,Address 
A,B,C
```

Then year2003.csv adds a new column

```
Age,Gender,Address,Location, 
A,B,C,D
```

By the time we get to year 2021, my CSV now has 7 columns and looks like this:

```
Age,Gender,Address,Location,Height,Weight,Race
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
```

My business wants to create a single CSV which contains all of the data recorded. Where data is not available, (for example, Address data is not recorded in the 2002 CSV) there can be a 0 or a NAAN or a empty cell.

What is the best method available to merge the CSV's into a single CSV? It may be worthwhile saying, that I have 15,000 CSV files which need to be merged. ranging from 2002-2021. 2002 the CSV starts off with three columns, but by 2020, the csv has 10 columns. I want to create one 'master' spreadsheet which contains all of the data.

Just a little extra context... I am doing this because I will then be using Python to replace the empty values using the new data. E.g. calculate an average and replace CSV empty values with that average.

Hope this makes sense. I am just looking for some direction on how to best approach this. I have been playing around with excel, power bi and python but I can not figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem?

Comment: Power BI - I have tried merging the CSV'S, however, it does not work properly due to the CSV files not sharing similar separator/delimiter. So essentially power BI does not recognise the columns correctly. I can get it to recognise how to do it correctly for some CSV, but because there is 15,000+ I can not get it to work for every single one.

Comment: For Python, I have been looking into the 'Merge, join, concatenate and compare' documentation for Pandas. However, none of the examples really reflect what I am trying to do. I believe that if I were to do it in Pandas, I would have to merge together values within Series or DataFrame columns? I am not sure if this is the most suitable method?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68090301/edit) instead of adding additional info in comments. try to include the details of what you've tried

Comment: Power BI allows splitting on multiple delimiters, so programming a query to deal with that issue should not be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

With pandas you can use `pandas.read_csv()` to create Dataframe, which you can merge using `pandas.concat()`.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv(csv1)
data2 = pd.read_csv(csv2)

data = pd.concat(data1, data2)
```

Comment: `pd.concat([data1, data2])` Notice, that you are supposed to pass in a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at python csv module.

A good place to start: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-csv-files-python/

It is simple and useful for reading CSVs and creating new ones.